# NW.js Chromium logging flags behave differently when specified in package.json

Tags: javascript, windows, chromium, node-webkit

I am experiencing different behaviour when using Chromium's `--enable-logging` flag as part of a NW.js application. On a Windows 10 machine, specifying the logging flag as part of the package.json `"chromium-args": "--enable-logging --v=1"` spawns two extra prompt windows in addition to the main window.

Searching the Chromium documentation suggested adding the `--no-sandbox` flag would solve this issue. Adding it to the package.json file did not change the behaviour.

However, providing the logging flag through the command line and not in the package.json file yields the desired result.

```
"App Name.exe" --enable-logging --v=1
```

The log file is generated as expected and no extra windows are spawned on launch. Why is there a difference when I specify the argument on the command line vs. in the chromium-args section of the package.json file? And secondly, how can I get the desired behaviour by specifying everything in the package?

Using NW.js version 0.16.1